# CakePHP on a Mac - Homebrew HTTPD

Tags: macos, cakephp, homebrew

I'm trying to run CakePHP 4 or 3.8 on macOS Catalina with Homebrew httpd and PHP 7.3.13 
I run composer as mentioned on cookbook and installation goes well but, when try to run te app via browser I get this error:

[safari screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcdsa.png)

[chrome screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bix86.png)

on error log message get "AH00052: child pid 10126 exit signal Illegal instruction (4)".

I have also the extensions intl, mbscript, pear, rewrite, etc enabled.

My virtual host is like this:

---

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/webdev/Sites/cakephp/webroot"
ServerName cakephp.localhost

<Directory "/Users/webdev/Sites/cakephp/webroot">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog "/Users/webdev/Sites/Error_Logs/error.log
```

---

the .htaccess file on root of app is:

RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteRule    ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
```

And in webroot folder is:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I've already tried many suggestions but nothing solve the problem.

I don't know what to do more because, just CakePHP don't work and i've other apps like Laravel and work like a charm on this machine.

If anyone can help with solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: As the errors are textual, can you please copy and paste those errors (or rewrite, since they're short) in the question body?

Comment: This is the apache error log:
[Sun Jan 12 20:37:55.857722 2020] [core:notice] [pid 11120] AH00052: child pid 11133 exit signal Illegal instruction (4)
[Sun Jan 12 20:37:55.857787 2020] [core:notice] [pid 11120] AH00052: child pid 11131 exit signal Illegal instruction (4)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what being wrong in my case.

When I configured *virtual host* and *hosts* file to "something.localhost" server dropped connection.

Changed configuration to "something.something_else" in httpd-username.conf and /etc/hosts, all cake instances start working.

This works for me.